# How to recursively select group of columns from panel data in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have cross-sectional data which consists of yearly crime frequencies in the chicago area and house price. I want to select a group of columns recursively from dataset because I want to use them as features for training regression model. Is there any quick way to do this? any idea?

**example data snippet**:

here is the screenshot of my data:

[image]
[image]

here is [example data snippet](https://filebin.net/ml0sjn455gr8pvh3) on the cloud for browsing data.

**my attempt**:

here is one example that I could select group of columns as features for the training ML model.

```
import urllib
import pandas as pd
# download data from cloud
u = "https://filebin.net/ml0sjn455gr8pvh3/crime_realEstate?t=7dkm15wq"
crime_realEstate = urllib.request.urlretrieve (u, "Ktest.csv")

# or just manually download data first and read
crime_realEstate = pd.read_csv('crime_realEstate.csv')
cols_2012 = crime_realEstate.filter(regex='_2012').columns
crime_realEstate['Area_Name']=crime_realEstate['Area_Name'].apply(lambda x: re.sub(' ', '_', str(x)))
regDF_2012 = crime_realEstate[cols_2012]
regDF_2012 = regDF_2012.assign(community_code=crime_finalDF['community_area'])
regDF_2012.dropna(inplace=True)
X_feats = regDF_2012.drop(['Avg_Price_2012'], axis=1)
y_label = regDF_2012['Avg_Price_2012'].values
```

basically, I want to do same things for `regDF_2013`, `regDF_2014` and so on in the loop for better manipulation and easy to access data.

any idea to make this happen? any thoughts? Thanks

Comment: What is the format of the final DataFrame you want? One row per year with all the features as columns?

Comment: @JamesSteele pandas dataframe. what I want is getting yearly crime type, respective avg house price along the community area. I don't want like what I did for `regDF_2012`, `regDF_2013` every time. Just want to access yearly cime type with avg house price for the `community area` along the year.

Comment: What do you want in the rows, and what do you want in the columns. Define the final dataframe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Melt your dataframe. This way you have separate column for each variable and index by Area_name. :

```
import pandas as pd
crime_realEstate = pd.read_csv("Ktest.csv", delimiter="\t", index_col=0)
crime_melted = pd.melt(crime_realEstate, id_vars=['Area_Name', 'community_area'])
crime_melted["crime"] = crime_melted["variable"].apply(lambda x: x[:-5])
crime_melted["year"] = crime_melted["variable"].apply(lambda x: x[-4:])
crime_melted.drop(columns=["variable"], inplace=True)
crime_melted.set_index("Area_Name", inplace=True)
```

Resulting dataframe is (example rows):

```
                community_area        value                crime  year
Area_Name                                                              
Grand Boulevard            38.0   135.000000              assault  2012
Grand Boulevard            38.0   108.000000              assault  2013
Grand Boulevard            38.0   116.000000              assault  2014
Grand Boulevard            38.0    78.000000              assault  2015
Grand Boulevard            38.0   105.000000              assault  2016
```

Index can be accessed by using loc:

```
crime_melted.loc["Grand Boulevard"]
```

Separate column for every variable is what you need for machine learning :-)